# JOIN returns only a single result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have to query a given table. I can't change the table structure. It's basically like this:

```
user
-- ---------- ----
id address_id name

address
-- ---
id zip

language
-- ----
id lang
```

Where the `id` of entries in *language* is the same as the *user's* `id`. Its primary key is based on `id` and `lang`. `address_id` on *user* can be `null`.

Now I want to get everything with a single query. I've tried:

```
SELECT
    p.name,
    l.lang,
    a.zip

FROM user p

JOIN language l ON p.id = l.id

LEFT JOIN address a ON p.address_id = a.id

WHERE p.id = :id

LIMIT 1
```

Which actually works except for one thing: It only returns the first language that is connected to the user. How can I retrieve all languages?

**Edit**

I'm retrieving the result using PHP PDO:

```
$value = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Could there be a mistake?

Comment: Remove the `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `p` instead of `e` in a few spots?

Comment: I've already tried that. Unfortunately this doesn't change the result set.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Correct. Fixed the question, I reduced this from a larger query.

Comment: Well, are there multiple records for that certain `id` in the language table?

Comment: To make it clearer: I want to return **1 user** with **all** his **attached languages**.

Comment: @Stijn Yes, checked that.

Comment: `p.id = l.id` seems the wrong join condition.

Comment: How _is_ language connected to a user? id<->id seems odd.

Comment: @lampshade Double check. If you still get only 1 record with the `LIMIT 1` removed, you have a data issue. It should work as far as I can see.

Comment: @Jack That's what I thought too, but what you be a right one then?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It seems that way. I think the database was created by symfony 1.4 using doctrine 1.

Comment: Perhaps there *is* no connection :)

Comment: @Jack If there's no connection, do I simply have to use a sub query to get all languages?

Comment: @lampshde is ID on the language table  a primary key or unique index? (I'm with the others removing limit should work so I'm trying to see if you even could have additional records in language or if structure prevents it.)

Comment: @xQbert I got those indexes on the language table: `PRIMARY: id, lang` (*unique*) and `language_id_idx: id` (*not unqiue*).

Comment: Thank you all for your help. With two answers I could nail it. It **was** the `Limit 1` in conjunction with `fetch` instead of `fetchAll`. Actually I would like to give you all an upvote for helping me. Thanks a lot. Highly appreciated. I expected only a single result. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing your query, I realize that you need to know about `LIMIT` clause in query.

Read the [tutorial of LIMIT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx).

You are using `LIMIT 1` in query, that's why it is retrieving only one row.
Remove that limit clause to get the full data from the query.

**EDITED:**

OR instead of your query try below query:

```
SELECT
    p.name,
    l.lang,
    a.zip
FROM user p, language l, address a
WHERE p.id = l.id AND p.address_id = a.id AND p.id = :id
```

Comment: Which, according to OP, gave the same result?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The moment I got those 15 rep, I'll come back and upvote too.

Comment: Finally got the rep. ;)

Answer (score 2):

[fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) will only fetch a single row. Use it in a loop like this:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Or [fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) rows at once.

As discussed already in the comments and in the answer by *Broken Heart ღ*, you should also remove the `LIMIT 1` statement.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The moment I got those 15 rep, I'll come back and upvote.

Comment: Finally got the rep. ;)